# How to create dbContext fake for unit testing repository methods

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

I have a method in Entity Framework concrete repository. It uses a Linq query that looks like this:

```
Table myTable = dbContext.Table.SingleOrDefault(t=>
                t.attribute1 == attribute1Value
                &&
                t.attribute2 == attribute2Value);
```

In my unit tests I tried to Shim dbContext. I want to use something like:

```
using (ShimsContext.Create())
{
    // Don't know what to use here.
}
```

I am struggling with the syntax here. Also if there is a way to get the dbContext stub instead of shimming it, please do let me know the correct approach.

Comment: I tend to get a bit worried when people try to use shims, because it usually means they're headed toward testing the wrong thing. In this case, I'm not sure what else you could do, if you can't wrap the context somehow and stub the wrapper. I'd certainly see what properties `Shim|insert_context_class_here|` offers, but it's going to get messy.

Comment: Personally I like to implement the Unit of Work and repository patterns as described [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application). It makes it easier to unit test.

Comment: It takes a bit of work, but you can create an interface that your DbContext will implement, then create a fake/stub/mock for this in your test project and inject it into classes using the DbContext. The key here is that your interface will have to use IDbSet for the entity collections and you'll have to create a fake for that in your test project to get it to return dummy data. It does get to the point of possible diminishing returns from a test perspective, but along with a good design, this might be viable (or un-necessary, depending on your point of view).

Comment: The link posted by rfernandes has great information, especially the generic repository implementation. If you go that route, you could fairly easily use a stub/mock for the DbContext and test your single repository class. Or accept a small gap in coverage but limit it by the fact that your data access code is simple and in one class.